# In an amp page, is it possible to include a .js file that executes code after window.onload?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

"In an amp page, is it possible to include a .js file that executes code after window.onload?"
I have been able to execute the .js with a button

```
<amp-script layout="container" src="amptest.js">
  <button id="hello" style="visibility:hidden;"></button>
</amp-script>
```

```
const button = document.getElementById('hello');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const el = document.createElement('h1');
  el.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
});

getUserLocation();
```

I started with a button that was visible.
I noticed that when the page is loading, the getUserLocation() is also executed, although not in the event listener function. So without clicking the button. Basically, that is what I need : that the code runs without a trigger. So I made the button invisible. When loading the page, the getUserlocation() is still executed. But preferably there is no button; the .js needs to run automatically.
And, I need it after the window.onload, not straight away.
I added a window.onload in the .js around the getUserLocation() but then this function is not executed.

is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not dead clear on your issue, but ... all events related to `amp-script` must be triggered by a gesture (a user action). AFAIK there is no "automatic" (background) processing. You can use serviceworker for some parallel actions that link to the DOM, but they are limited.

Comment: Thank you Jay. Sorry, took a long time to respond. Lack of knowledge was my issue here. I discovered that you actually can execute js code without a user trigger. So if f.e. you have a blank div and you wrap it in a script tag with a src to your .js file then that code is executed immediately when the page is loading. So you can do background stuff like get the user location or whatever. You can also change field values; f.e. have js put text in that div without a user trigger. I believe (by experience) this only works on html elements, not on amp elem. For amp-elements user trigger is req.

Comment: But, that said and back to my question, Yes you can execute code without user trigger, but I believe there is no such thing as a window.onload since the script tag wraps an element and only has access to that element. I believe a worker does not have access to the dom.